# Destroy an object with variables (free memory)

Tags: c++, object, memory, free

I am trying to create an event/date organizer in C++.
The overview is like a calender show one month and every Day in this calender is an Object (type: EventCell)
The class EventCell stores the events for his day in a vector (name: eventData with type: "EventInfo": class for storing day, name, start/endtime).

But when I switch the month I want to clear this vector, destroy all of its objects and free the memory of its variables. I tried this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < terminData.size(); i++)
{
    delete terminData[i];
}
terminData.clear();
```

It calls the Deconstructor but the variables etc are still alive.
If I make this for example:

```
terminData[0]->getDay(); 
result: 3
```

I still get the value of the Variable from the deleted object...

I think if I don't delete everything its probably gets to big, because every time I change the month, it is creating an object for every event.

Any suggestions how I could actually delete an object with its variable etc to get back the memory and create an new?

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer to unallocated memory leads to *undefined behavior*. Just don't do it. As for *why* you can still access the data is because the system doesn't waste precious CPU cycles to clear the data you free.

Comment: When you call `terminData[0]->getDay();`, `terminData[0]` is unallocated because you just deleted it.

Comment: Not only is the pointed to object unallocated, but the pointer `terminData[0]` itself was deleted as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I still get the value of the Variable from the deleted object...

No, you get a garbage value. By accessing `terminData[0]` after `terminData.clear();` you've invoked undefined behaviour.

> Any suggestions how I could actually delete an object with its variable etc to get back the memory and create an new?

You've already deleted the objects successfully. To create new objects, construct them as you did the originals. The memory of the old objects is free to be used by other objects.

Comment: No its the exact value.. i tried it by 
[code]
     <cout << "Day: " << terminData[i]->getDay() << endl;
        delete terminData[i];
        cout << "Day: " << terminData[i]->getDay() << endl;

Comment: Whether it's the same value as it used to be is irrelevant, it's still garbage.

Comment: @Marius So what? The compiler is not required to give you a *different* value when you invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: You sure? So I can just create the new object over it and it wont metters?

Comment: @user2079303: Yes. but i was unsure, because I didn't know if the object and its variable were successful delete or not.... It was a bit confusing to me...

Comment: @Marius It won't matter. When you create a new object, it will overwrite the memory that was there before it (assuming the object initializes all of it's own memory, some simple objects might not). There is no way to tell if a location in memory contains a valid object or not, you have to make sure that it does by yourself (by not accessing random locations in memory, including unallocated pointers).

Comment: @Marius You can create a new object, and it *might* be in the same location as the object you freed before. Or it might not be. After you called `delete`, the operating system is free to do with that memory as it pleases. It's no longer yours.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing raw owning pointers in the vector, as your code with explicit delete calls makes me think:

> ```
> for (unsigned int i = 0; i < terminData.size(); i++)
> {
>     delete terminData[i];
> }
> ```

I would just use a vector of smart pointers, for example `vector<unique_ptr<YourData>>`. In this case, a simple `terminData.clear()` call will *automatically* delete the pointed objects.

Note also that you may want to have a simpler `vector<YourData>` as well.

The fact that you reference deleted memory and you get what may appear as a valid result doesn't mean your code is correct, or that the memory was not correctly deleted either. Referencing deleted memory is *undefined behavior*, so you just shouldn't do that.

It's possible that the memory allocator or the CRT or some other component just marked the previously allocated memory as free, without "physically" deleting the data previously stored there. So this might be a reason why you can access previous data from deleted pointers. But this is just *undefined behavior*, this is *not* guaranteed to work in other contexts, with other versions of the compiler or the runtime library implementation, etc. So, just fix your code and don't do that.

Comment: I never worked with smart pointers. Could you please tell me how I have to create them? 
Because [code]vector <unique_prt<TerminInfo>> terminDaten;[/code] doesnt work... and I have no clue how to do this...

Comment: @Marius: Smart pointers are very convenient. You may want to open a new question with a reproducible code snippet not compiling, and the exact error message you get, so we can give you better help.